# Convert Binary to Text

Tags: code-golf, math, binary, conversion

Your task is to write a program, which takes a binary input and converts it to plain text. For Example:

```
01100001 01100010 01100011 = "abc"
```

### Rules

- Input can come from STDIN, function arguments, command line argument, file, whatever suits you.
- The program can be a function, full program,  whatever works, really, as long as no external uncounted code/arguments are needed to run it.
- You can assume that the input is valid.
- The length of the input is **not** limited
- You can assume that all blocks are seperated with whitespaces

### Test Cases

```
01010100 01100101 01110011 01110100 = "Test"
01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 = "Hello"
01010111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100 00001101 00001010 = "World"
01000101 01111000 01100001 01101101 01110000 01101100 01100101 00001101 00001010 = "Example"
01100010 01101001 01101110 00001101 00001010 = "bin"
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution wins.

Comment: Do mean we *can* or we *must* assume that all blocks are separated with whitespaces?

Comment: @Dada you **can**

Comment: Why does this look related to the binary heart challenge? Most answer there is just a text to binary converter.

Comment: What input formats are allowed? For example, an 8-column matrix of zeros and ones? A 2D array of chars?

Comment: Can I take the binary blocks with no separator (no space)?

Comment: @seshoumara Yes, you can.

Comment: You should really wait a few days to weeks before picking an accepted answer. What if someone manages shorter than 4 bytes in a few hours or days?

Comment: Why is the dc answer accepted at all? The 05AB1E answer was first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
#CçJ
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6/sfHi51///BoZgaKBgYAgkgUwQA8SCMoBMAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 4 bytes

Needs as input the binary blocks with no separator. This is allowed by the OP.

```dc
2i?P
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@2@UaR/w/7@BoaEBEBhCaCCG0IYA)**

**Explanation:** using the "abc" example as test case

- `2i?` sets 2 as input radix, then reads the line (output radix is 10 by default). This converts the binary input to decimal: 011000010110001001100011 -> 6382179.
- `P` is a special printing mode that assumes a base 256 number, using its "digits" as ASCII codes: 6382179 = (**97** * 256 <sup>2</sup>) + (**98** * 256 <sup>1</sup>) + (**99** * 256 <sup>0</sup>) -> **abc**

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 15 bytes

14 bytes of code + `-p` flag.
The input must be supplied *without* final newline (with `echo -n` for instance).

```perl
$_=pack"B*",$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1YsSC3KUdAtyPmvEm9bkJicreSkpaSjEv//v4GhoQEQGEJoIIbQhlwgIQMI2wDCNoTIgmggiwus2ABFAUwzEg03ydAQJgA1CUUhxCSIENQ9EBtgmuE2GcBtghpkgG6QIRaDEJ4zhBtgiGEjAA)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

```
s=>String.fromCharCode(...s.split` `.map(s=>`0b`+s))
```

Answer (score 2):

### sed and dc, <strike>23</strike>, 19 bytes

```
sed 's/.*/2i&P/'|dc
```

Comment: Why not just `'s/.*/2i&P/'`?

Comment: @Neil: good point

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 7 Bytes

```
smCid2c
```

Takes input as string.

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=smCid2c&input=%2201100001+01100010+01100011%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%2201100001+01100010+01100011%22%0A%2201010100+01100101+01110011+01110100%22%0A%2201001000+01100101+01101100+01101100+01101111%22%0A%2201010111+01101111+01110010+01101100+01100100+00001101+00001010%22%0A%2201000101+01111000+01100001+01101101+01110000+01101100+01100101+00001101+00001010%22%0A%2201100010+01101001+01101110+00001101+00001010%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 49 bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#PYpBCoAwDAS/Erw0AZHUo@ArvHrRilipVWr/X9OKblgYMuv6MbnpmJcJhk6pZj@tR7MFtD6iqVui9QxgwHoYmvtyNiJRuoJocFixZpZqYC0RzsD5V0B/ij@V8d0UlZc/yFWUHg)

```
lambda S:''.join(chr(int(c,2))for c in S.split())
```

Comment: Do you need the `'0b'+` as well as the `,2`?

Comment: @Neil Yes, `chr()` accepts only [0-255] integers and binary in python represented like `0bxxxxxx`. So first I need to add 0b to binary blocks and then convert them into basic int to get chars. While converting, I need to specify base of input - 2.

Comment: @ovs Oh, thats true! Unintuitive :)

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by  using list comprehension! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#PYrRCoAgDAB/ZfTSBhGzx6AvqR7UiAyzsP7fZlEbg2N3vhuS15uZNJi2LOt1dwF7u0R04UJbNUQw7xEsuACmPg/vLqSR0hElAI8FK2Y5BaxkhDNw/j2gPsWfyvg2j8rlD7IFpRs "Python 2 – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran Good one! I've saved even more. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 10 bytes

```
û{$-2Bo}r.
```

## Explained

```
û          # Split the implicit input by Spaces.
 {     }r  # Replace each element in a list based on a function.
  $-2B     # Convert from Base 2
      o    # Get the ordinal of the character.
         . # Concatenate the list.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn-2#@394d7WKrpFTfm2R3v///w0MwdBAwcAQSAKZIAaIBWUAmQA)

Answer (score 1):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 10 bytes

```
l:~8/2fb:c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@59jVWehb5SWZJX8/7@BoYEBEBsqGBgCAZANYhiAxMAMQ5iUAUwKxISoAUuBVMIZQAgA)

#### Explanation

```
l    e# Read input.
:~   e# Evaluate each character, resulting in a flat list of bits.
8/   e# Split into chunks of 8 bits.
2fb  e# Convert each from binary to an integer.
:c   e# Convert each integer to a character.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 50 bytes

```
FromCharacterCode[#~FromDigits~2&/@StringSplit@#]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
{split|chr parseInteger(_,radix=2)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/roda#y03MzFOoVkizjflfXVyQk1lSk5xRpFCQWFSc6plXkpqeWqQRr1OUmJJZYWukWfufs6C0OENDycDQ0AAIDBUgDEMDGMNQSVOhRiGNq/Y/AA)

This is an anonymous function that reads the input from the stream and prints the result.

It uses three builtins:

- `split` splits the input at whitespaces
- `parseInteger` converts a binary string to an integer value
- `chr` converts an integer to a Unicode character

Answer (score 1):

## Gema, 33 characters

```
<D><s>=@int-char{@radix{2;10;$1}}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '<D><s>=@int-char{@radix{2;10;$1}}' <<< '01010000 01010000 01000011 01000111'
PPCG
```

### Gema, 31 characters

Using no delimiter in the input.

```
<D8>=@int-char{@radix{2;10;$1}}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '<D8>=@int-char{@radix{2;10;$1}}' <<< '01010000010100000100001101000111'
PPCG
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 36 characters

```ruby
->b{b.gsub(/\d+ ?/){$&.to_i(2).chr}}
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> ->b{b.gsub(/\d+ ?/){$&.to_i(2).chr}}['01010000 01010000 01000011 01000111']
=> "PPCG"
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP <5.3, 53 Bytes

Idea by [@manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork)

```
foreach(split(" ",$argv[1])as$v)echo chr(bindec($v));
```

## PHP, 55 Bytes

I prefer cause it can work without spaces

```
foreach(str_split($argv[1],9)as$v)echo chr(bindec($v));
```

without spaces change `9` to `8` for 7 bits `7`

```
foreach(explode(" ",$argv[1])as$v)echo chr(bindec($v));
```

### PHP >=7, 62 Bytes

```
<?=join(($a=array_map)(chr,$a(bindec,explode(" ",$argv[1]))));
```

Comment: Is this PHP 7? Can't make it work due to a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, but before you were able to use the deprecated `split()` function, so the length would be the same.

Comment: Uhm, I also tried `str_split()`, but is the same length as `explode()`. And both are 2 characters longer than `split()`. [insert confused smiley here]

Comment: @manatwork I think I was the only confused one. I like it not make post with deprecated functions. I mean str_split in combine with the foreach loop is the best solution cause it can handle other inputs with little changes

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 43 bytes

```c
f(**v){*v&&f(v+!!putchar(strtol(*v,0,2)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCgIhFEX3fsWbWQw@c0DbSl8SLURwGjCL0Wwh/novJwi6q8PlHq6bXbBxIfJciIJVlGnyvByG4fHM7mo3nvKW74GLIpU8IqJptMYMN7tGjlAZ9OxDAcWGdL7ACSqMSmvVo0f5Y63@eO8VNMO@ej/sKhrW6O18sEui@fUB)

Comment: @ceilingcat, nice but we could have simply used `strtol`.

Answer (score 0):

### Jelly, *unfinished*

I still haven't figure out how to `repeat for every line in STDIN`, or get `amount of lines in STDIN` in Jelly. So far though, I came up for a solution for a single line/character.

```
ɠO_48ḄỌ
```

Any help is appreciated!